# Публикация фотографии в альбом VK

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

https://vk.com/dev/upload_files
В документации не понятно сказано, про 2 этап.
1 этап получить сервер для загрузки - это я сделал.
2 этап **POST** запросом отправить фотографию, а сервер вернет ответ для 3 этапа.

В интернете все только про PHP и Pyhton.

```
string url = "https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getUploadServer?group_id=" + 
groupid + "&album_id=" + album + "&access_token=" + token;
var r = c.DownloadString(url);
string[] a = r.Split('"', '&');
url = ParseUrl(a[5], true);
var r2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(c.UploadFile(url, "POST", imagePath));
```

Сервер возвращает "Security Breach2" в документации про это не слово, что делать?

UPD: **Прошу варианты без использования библиотек xNet, vkNet, VkApi и прочего.**

Comment: Честно говоря, не понимаю зачем вам это надо (именно такая реализация). Существует вообще то Vk Net библиотека для целей работы с ВК (https://vknet.github.io/vk/). Используйте её и всё будет проще...

Comment: Только с аудио работать не будет. В декабре прошлого года ВК запретил работу с аудиозаписями в stalone приложениях в целях соблюдения авторских прав.

Comment: Ну, если вам только в образовательных целях типа разобраться. Но если писать конкретное приложение, то стоит использовать vknet (там вся эта "головная боль" была решена для вас). Могу предложить в таком случае поизучать исходники этой библиотеки: https://vk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest.

Comment: Кстати, если вам удастся разобраться, не могли бы вы кинуть мне исходник авторизации и какой-нибудь работы с аудио? Давно хотел для себя бота написать по управлению аудиозаписями, да всё руки не доходят...

Comment: Это я знаю. Это кстати я вам и написал выше. Но запрет - ТОЛЬКО для stalone приложений. С браузера же спокойно можно работать с музыкой. Да забейте. Я так..

Answer (score 0):

Второй этап :

```
var imagelink = request.Get(url).ToString();
imagelink = Pars(imagelink, "upload_url\":\"", "\"", 0).Replace("\\", "");
request.AddFile("file1", @image);
    
var s9 = request.Post(imagelink).ToString();


private string Pars(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd, int startPos)
{
    try
    {
        int length = strStart.Length;
        string str = "";
        int num1 = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, startPos);
        int num2 = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, num1 + length);
        if (num1 != -1 & num2 != -1)
            str = strSource.Substring(num1 + length, num2 - (num1 + length));
        return str;
    }
    catch { return ""; }
}
```

в переменной `s9` будет ответ от сервера, где будут поля `server, photos_list, hash, aid` скопируйте их и пошлите в методе [save](https://vk.com/dev/photos.save)

p.s использовал библиотеку xNet

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то давно писал я бота, помню, что тоже больно мучился с выгрузкой файлов, ибо освещена эта тема в документации ВК кое-как (позже я вовсе писал свою библиотеку для взаимодействия с VK API и раз 15-20 писал в поддержку о том, что документация не соответствует действительности). Привожу пример кода (в нем используются некоторые мои функции и глобальные переменные, однако из их названия понятно, что они делают и чем являются + это больше относится только к получению ссылки для выгрузки, а с этим у Вас проблем не было)):

```
    private string UploadPhoto(string path, string photoName)
    {
        try
        {
            string uploadURL = client.DownloadString("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getMessagesUploadServer.xml?access_token=" + User.Token.Token + "&v=" + App.APIVersion).ParseXML("upload_url")[0]; 
            string fileInfo = Upload(uploadURL, "photo", path, photoName);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileInfo)) return string.Empty;
            fileInfo = fileInfo.Replace("\\", "");
            string fileNameNew = "[" + fileInfo.SubstringIndex(fileInfo.LastIndexOf('{'), fileInfo.IndexOf('}')) + "]";
            string[] data = fileInfo.Split(new char[] { ':', '"', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string server = data[data.IndexOf("server") + 1];
            string hash = data[data.IndexOf("hash") + 1];
            string fileURL = client.DownloadString("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.saveMessagesPhoto.xml?photo=" + fileNameNew + "&server=" + server + "&hash=" + hash + "&access_token=" + User.Token.Token);
            return fileURL;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Error.ChangeValue(ex.Message); }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

На 6 строчке идет вызов метода Upload, который является общим для выгрузки любых документов на сервер ВК. Вот он:

```
    private string Upload(string actionUrl, string graph, string path, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpContent bytesContent = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
            using (var client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20) })
            using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                formData.Add(bytesContent, graph, fileName);
                var response = client.PostAsync(actionUrl.Replace("&amp;", "&"), formData).Result;
                return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        } catch (Exception) { return string.Empty; }
    }
```

Поясню входные данные: 
 **actionUrl** - ссылка для выгрузки (та, которую возвращает Вам "первый этап"); 
 **graph** - не помню, почему ее так назвал, однако обозначает она тип документа. В вашем случае это `"photo"`; 
**path** - путь к файлу; 
 **fileName** - как файл должен быть назван на сервере ВК

---

Вот, как-то так. Гарантировать полную работоспособность методов не могу, к сожалению, так как писал я это без малого 2.5 года назад. Так что отпишите потом комментарий, помогло ли Вам сие. Надеюсь, что общие принципы сильно не изменились) 
 
 **P.S.** - И да, за код сильно не бейте, я знаю, что это можно было написать в разы чище, но, как я уже говорил, писал я это `2.5 года назад`, а любому порядочному программисту стыдно смотреть на свой код уже месячной давности)